# Where would I post a question about how to do something in programming (without having code in the question)

Tags: discussion, support, meta

I have a question that I would like answered but don't have code involved (because I have not created the application yet). It is essentially how can I do a thing in node.js or can you point me to a resource to learn how I can do this thing.

This is likely a question which would get flagged in stack overflow

Comment: Start by reading existing questions or other sites on the Internet.  Such questions are too broad for this network, which also explains why they would be problematic on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I would not expect to find such a site on Stack Exchange because the starting point for help with code is usually the posting of a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Asking for what you would need to learn, and from where, will be too broad for focussed Q&A because it elicits a list of resources and/or personal tuition.